# System.out.println printing only a blank line

Tags: java, console, netbeans-8

For my Swing application, I'm printing to the console (as you do) to debug. However, only a blank line is printed when I print to the console.
This may be because my compilation settings may have altered themselves.

I'm running the application on a Windows 10 computer in the NetBeans 8.2 IDE. At first, I though it was a EDT problem (since that was where it was printing) so I moved it outside that, then to the first line of the main method. As such, it should definitely execute, but the results are no different.

Online, I found [a similar problem](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=117048), but I can't change the settings that the answers are referring to.

A minimal and complete example.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

This is a simple `Hello World` application, but it only prints a blank line.

Therefore, it should print `Hello World!` Instead, only a blank line is printed.

[image: A screenshot of my problem: nothing is printed except a blank line]

[image: And highlighted to prove it]

Comment: if you attempt to click/drag as to "highlight" the output - does anything show up? In other words, is the output for some reason white in color?

Comment: I went through that _"a similar problem"_ you have mentioned. This may be a bug in NetBeans. Switch to "IntelliJ IDEA". It is a much better IDE. :)

Comment: @PrasadKarungoda I have IntelliJ IDEA but I've been working with NetBeans for 5 years and it'd be hard to switch.

Comment: @vapurrmaid nothing shows up. Please see edits.

Comment: Is it possible that you're not running the project containing `HelloWorld.java`? Your window says "ScheduleHelp" - is `HelloWorld.java` in that project? Furthermore, you should be able to right click on the project and go to **properties > run** - does the expected `Main class` show?

Comment: Another potential: at the top of window what does **Run > Set Main Project** say? It should be `none`.

Comment: @vapurrmaid both things are as expected. Yes, `HelloWorld.java` is in the project, but it's not the main class. Even if I set it as the main class, the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

With the help of `git bisect`, I figured out that one little change was making the difference.

The problem started I added this to my `project.properties` file in the `nbproject` folder in my NetBeans project:

```
run.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=Unicode
```

Moral of the story: use `git bisect` when something truly is wrong and you need to revert stuff and don't do stuff you don't understand. :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine when I run it. I'm using Eclipse and you're using Netbeans but that shouldn't cause any problems. Perhaps you didn't save it already

Comment: As I said in the question, it's likely my `config` settings. My code isn't a problem; it's a simple Hello World snippet.